# How to rewrite query without selfjoin

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a view, that run next query

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.Id AS Id
    , R.app
    , case when R2.EventTypeId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END AS type   
FROM user R
left join user R2 on R.Id = R2.Id 
and R2.EventTypeId > 0 
and R2.Date > '2022-10-16'
WHERE R.Date between '2022-10-16' and '2022-10-30' 
AND R.EventTypeId = 0
```

Is there any way to rewrite it without self join?

Date is partitiong field with filter retuire on.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a window function. Please check that all conditions are included.

```
SELECT Id, app,
max(type)
from(
Select *, 
max( case when EventTypeId IS NOT NULL and EventTypeId > 0  and Date > '2022-10-16'  THEN 1 END) over (partition by Id) AS type   
FROM user R
WHERE Date between '2022-10-16' and '2022-10-30' # limits both time areas
)
WHERE Date between '2022-10-16' and '2022-10-30' # limits only the time area of the displayed 
AND EventTypeId = 0 
group by 1,2
```

Comment: for R2.Date there must be no limit by end date